# SQL query with LIKE / wildcards, Optimization

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

I have the following string in a database:

```
"[] some text [] 15" (other strings: "sometext15", "text", "[] [] another text []", "something else []").
```

The brackets are placeholders. When I search for the string, I don't know on which position or how much brackets I have to expect. I only know, that they appear before/after words, separated by a blank.

Therefore I want to find this string by using following search terms:

```
"some text 15"
```

or

```
"some text [] 15"
```

or

```
"[] some text 15"
```

Currently I have a rather slow approach. I remove all brackets in the search string and replace all blanks with " **%**".

So my search query looks like this:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
WHERE X LIKE '%some%text%15%'
```

From the answer I have to filter out unsuitable answers like "*sometext15*".

This works, but is quite slow. I have to make a lot of queries, so speed is critical.

Do you have any ideas for an optimized/better query or solution for this problem? Any idea for a more specific query?

Thank You!

Mark

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ? If you are using Oracle, you could look at REGEXP functions.

Comment: Sadly it's a MSAccess DB, which I connect to via .Net/OleDB/Jet. Regex is not available for this, as far as I know. This would be to good to be true...

Comment: Text search optimization is very hard. If you have the hability to change the Data model, maybe it would be more efficient to store this String in more columns (1 column per place holder) ?

Comment: Sadly altering the database is not an option. It is an old long-grown database and I am not allowed to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following suggestion: 
Create a Lookup_table which contains ID and words columns. Then insert all of the expressions that you need into that table, in your case:

```
 insert into Lookup_table (id, words) values
 (1, 'some text 15'),
 (2, 'some text [] 15'), 
 (3,'some text 15')
```

Once you have that, perform the following query:

```
 select * from YourTableName
 where YourColumnName in (select Words from lookup_table)
```

Since Ms-Access does not support Contains function, I feel using a lookup table would make it much faster because it is indexed.

Comment: While I like your idea, but sadly I am not allowed to alter the database. And I am not sure, if this would be faster, since there are many possibilities and the lookup table would become huge.